# ffmpeg slideshow on raspberry pi raspbian

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer, ffmpeg, h264

I'm trying to make a slideshow video from few (in this case 3) .jpgs. To do this, I'm using

```
    ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i bat%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p proba12.mp4
```

and actually it works on Windows (it plays every image for 5 seconds), but on Raspbian, it doesn't work, neither on omxplayer nor hello_video.bin (in h264).

Here is what the console shows:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i bat%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p proba12.mp4
ffmpeg version N-89047-g54f8ac199f Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1) 20170516
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavcodec     58.  3.101 / 58.  3.101
  libavformat    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  0.101 /  7.  0.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'bat%03d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080             
[SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x31ac620] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec     - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r               ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fa               st_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3                b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree               =1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'proba12.mp4':
  Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf58.2.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc58.3.101 libx264
Side data:
  cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  449 fps=8.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1341kB time=00:00:14.86 bitrate= 738.9kbits/s dup=446 drop=0 speed=0.265x
video:1335kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.457740%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] frame I:3     Avg QP:15.58  size:442255
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] frame P:113   Avg QP:18.36  size:   130
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] frame B:333   Avg QP:27.00  size:    74
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] consecutive B-frames:  1.1%  0.0%  0.0% 98.9%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] mb I  I16..4:  2.0% 94.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.6%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.9%  L0:19.2% L1:80.8% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] 8x8 transform intra:94.5% inter:61.3%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 85.4% 31.7% 25.4% inter: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 43% 20%  9% 29%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 11% 33%  5%  7%  6%  8%  5%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 14% 15%  7% 11%  8%  9%  9%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 82%  8%  7%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] ref P L0: 99.5%  0.0%  0.4%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] ref B L0: 71.2% 28.6%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] ref B L1: 99.1%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] kb/s:730.29
```

What is also strange, if I'm trying to concatenate those files using text file and I set duration to 5 for every single file it makes a different display time... in this example, the first one displays for 15 seconds, the second one for 5 seconds and the last one for 10 seconds... of course this way of merging images doesn't work under Raspbian either.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3b with the latest Raspbian Noobs onboard.

Can you guys please direct me on a solution? I ran out of ideas...